# Highcharts How to bring tooltip above drill up button

Tags: highcharts

I have a drill down report, it's tool tip is going behind the drillupbutton. How to bring the tool tip front/above of the drillupbutton?

`Fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/rvg3dw4q/1/

To replicate drill down parent and place cursor on the last column.

Comment: In that case, tooltip is displayed in the bottom of column not top. You can use [tooltip positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) to reorganise position.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the  following:

```
"tooltip":{"xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y",followPointer:true},
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvg3dw4q/2/)

hopefully it helps